# Football league database structure. 1 sheet or 20 single sheets?

Tags: sql, excel, database-design

I am creating a database for a league with 20 teams. I currently have all the details for each team in separate sheets in excel and I am unsure if It would be better to put all the teams players into one sheet or leave them as the 20 different sheets before I convert it into csv for sql manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Almost for sure you want 1 table not 20.  Just make sure you have a team variable so each record is marked and you'll be able to easily do group by to get at specific team information

Comment: Thought as much. Thanks

Comment: if you liked the answer just accept it, much more rewarding then a comment!

Comment: Did not mean to offend. Thanks for the advice and I have now changed my database into one table.